# What's the most object-oriented way to design an address book?

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design

I am asking myself how to design an object-oriented address book in Java.

Let's say a contact can have several contact details, like addresses, phone numbers and e-mail addresses.

One way to implement this would be to give every contact an `ArrayList` for every type. But there must be a better and more object-oriented solution. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most OOP suggestion I can give you is to create a class for every item/piece of information. For example:

```
public abstract class ContactInfo { /* ... */ }

public class Address extends ContactInfo { /* ... */ }

public class PhoneNumber extends ContactInfo { /* ... */ }

public class EmailAddress extends ContactInfo { /* ... */ }

public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private Set<ContactInfo> info;
    // ...
}
```

and finally,

```
public class AddressBook {
    List<Contact> contacts;
    // ...
}
```

This may or may not be overkill for your specific case, but as a thought experiment, it's the way to go. It obviously takes care of the literal part of OOP — using objects — but also lays groundwork for encapsulation, abstraction and inheritance, which are closely related principles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how would I determine which type the contacts entry is?

Comment: @Mark, you wouldn't, with the exact code I provided here. In any real program, you'd have to do some tailoring to meet your unique requirements. If you need to know types offhand, having `Set<Address> addresses; Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;` might be the way to go. (I'm assuming that you meant the info entry rather than the contacts entry.)

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. The only thing I would do differently would be to use a [List interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) instead of an ArrayList collection to reference the contacts' attribute collections. This is advice based on the code-to-interfaces rule-of-thumb as described in [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html) and many others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's particularly un-object oriented.  If your domain is such that a `Person` can have zero or more `EmailAddress`es, then you've almost exactly described the situation to use a list.

The only alternative approach I can think of would be to have fields such as

```
WorkEmail
PersonalEmail
OtherEmail1
OtherEmail2
OtherEmail3
```

but in my opinion that's worse, because:

- You simply cannot support more than five email addresses (well, you could add more fields, but that increases the pain of the latter points and still imposes some finite limit.)
- You're implying some extra semantics than may be present (what if the same address is used for work and personal?  What if neither applies, can you just fill the `Other` ones?  What if you don't know the purpose?)
- You now have to test each field manually to see which is null, which is going to involve a non-trivial amount of duplication in Java.  You can't use nice features like the enhanced-for loop to apply the same block to every email address, and you can't trivially count how many addresses there are
- The list of properties that a `Person` has is now much less clean.  I suppose you could package these properties into an `EmailContactDetails` class or something, but now you've got an extra level of indirection (more conceptual complexity) for no real gain.

---

So, if a person has a possibly-empty, unbounded list of email addresses, what's wrong with representing that as a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and then get specific values e.g. via `myMap.get("emailAdress1")` or iterate over the whole map like you would do with a list via `myMap.entrySet()`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to handle most of the use cases can be like this

```
public class AddressBook {
    private Map<String, Contact> contacts;
    
    AddressBook(){
        contacts = new HashMap<String, Contact>();
    }
    
    public boolean addContact(Contact contact) {
        if(contacts.containsKey(contact.getName())) {
            System.out.println("Already exists");
            return false;
        }
        contacts.put(contact.getName(), contact);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean updateContact(Contact contact) {
        contacts.put(contact.getName(), contact);
        return true;
    }
}

class Contact{
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private Address address;
    
    public Contact(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Contact(String name, String email, String phone, Address address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
    }

    // getters and setters
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name is "+name+" and address is "+address;
    }
}

class Address{
    private String street1;
    private String street2;
    private String city;
    private int zipcode;
    
    public Address() {}

    // getters and setters
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "street1 is "+street1+" and zipcode is "+zipcode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some helpful instructions to help who is in doubt. Just dropping a piece of code will not be that helpul.